# Unable to disable transparent_hugepage/defrag to never in centOS 7.2

Tags: linux, centos7, mongodb

I am following this link,
https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/transparent-huge-pages/

I am getting the output

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
[always] madvise never
```

This is what i did

1)Create the following file at /etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepages:

```
case $1 in
  start)
    if [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage ]; then
      thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage
    elif [ -d /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage ]; then
      thp_path=/sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage
    else
      return 0
    fi

    echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/enabled
    echo 'never' > ${thp_path}/defrag

    unset thp_path
    ;;
esac
```

2) run

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/disable-transparent-hugepages
```

3) run

```
sudo chkconfig --add disable-transparent-hugepages
```

4)run

```
sudo mkdir /etc/tuned/no-thp
```

5)  Create and edit /etc/tuned/no-thp/tuned.conf so that it contains the following:

```
[main]
include=virtual-guest

[vm]
transparent_hugepages=never
```

6)run

```
sudo tuned-adm profile no-thp
```

7)

```
cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]

cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
[always] madvise never
```

8) same result even after restart server
Please help me
Thank you

Comment: I don't understand why the mongodb documentation recommends to use a init script to make kernel parameters persistent. IMHO the correct way is to use `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: `/etc/sysctl.conf` [isn't web-scale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs).

Answer (score 0):

I added this in the /etc/init.d/mongod after #!/bin/bash

```
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
fi
if test -f /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag; then
   echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag
fi
```

it work fine